# Remainder terms in the proof of central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

In the proof of central limit theorem via moment generating function, there is the following step:
$$M\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt t}\right)= 1+ \sigma^2\frac{t^2}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$$
Is it necessary to assume finite third moment to use taylor's inequality to derive this step? How can it be derived assuming finite second moment?

The proof is on page 6 of  [this document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_S096F13_lecnote3.pdf) .